# Scripts to deploy and interact with smart contract in remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, remix, ganache

I'm building a smart contract in solidity and using remix plugging for VSCode to deploy and test the same. I have a local network using ganache, and connecting remix to it (http://127.0.0.1:8545) to deploy my contract and test.
Problem is every time I modify any function in my contract, I have to redeploy and re-do all the transaction to finally test the function I made changes to.
Is there a way to write a script to deploy the smart contract and call all the functions that I know is working fine and jump on to test the modified function using remix IDE.?

I tried to deploy the smart contract using truffle migrations, but that deployed contract is not to be found in remix IDE to further carry on my testing.

Example scenario: I'm working on a airline ticket booking contract. Now to test a function which books the ticket, I need to first call some functions to add new airline and flights (which I want to automat)

Answer (score 0):

You can write automated tests and test your dapp and funcations automaticly.
check this remix plugin:
https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting.html